# How to show the inequation by using Hessian comparison.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In the below picture ,how to show the inequation 1?

In fact,I'm not familiar with Hessian comparison.So, hope a detail answer , Thanks very much.

The below picture is form 194th page of [here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see what look like several useful references just googling "Hessian comparison". I think Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry* is also a good reference for this kind of comparison.

Comment: In case it's not clear to you the "Hessian comparison" is taking place in the estimate $|\nabla^2 s| \le C_2 / s + \sqrt M$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks ,I try it .

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  Sorry, at the first line of 1, why $\frac{1}{r}g''\frac{1}{r^2}4s^2\nabla s\cdot\nabla s+\frac{1}{r}g'2\nabla s\cdot \nabla s\leq\frac{C^1}{r}$?

Comment: And the $\frac{1}{r}g'2s\nabla^2s\leq\frac{C^1}{r}|s\nabla^2s|$   I can't get too.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Besides, there just be a function $s$, the comparison theorem is about two function ,how to use it ? Very sorry ,I'm not familiar with comparison theorem ,May I have a detail answer, thanks.

Comment: The comparison theorem estimates the Hessian of the distance function $s$ in terms of the equivalent quantity in a constant-curvature space (here of curvature $-\sqrt M$ if I'm correct). You can get the other estimates by using the fact that $g'$, $g''$ are bounded, $s \le r$ and $|\nabla s| = 1$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks ,I have got the first line under your hint.But I still can't understand how to use comparison theorem. The space is not constant-curvature ,it's $|Rm|<M$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hessian comparison theorem is:

> If the sectional curvatures of a manifold are bounded below by $M$, then the distance function $s(x) = d(p,x)$ satisfies $\nabla^2 s \le \nabla^2_M s_M$, where $s_M$ is the corresponding distance function on the space of constant curvature $M$.
>
> [see e.g. [*ON THE DISTRIBUTIONAL HESSIAN OF THE DISTANCE FUNCTION* by Mantegazza, Mascellani & Uraltsev](http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/2113/HessBV.pdf).]

We know $|R_{ijkl}|<M$ and thus our sectional curvatures $K(e_i,e_j) = R_{ijij}$ satisfy $K > -M$; so we can compare to the hyperbolic space with curvature $-M$. In polar coordinates this space has metric $$g_M = ds^2 + \frac1M \sinh^2(\sqrt M s) d\Omega^2$$ where $d \Omega^2$ is the round metric on the unit $(n-1)$-sphere. The Hessian of the distance function is (see e.g. Petersen Chapter 2.3) $$\nabla^2s_M = \frac1{\sqrt M} \sinh(\sqrt M s) \cosh(\sqrt M s) d\Omega^2 = \sqrt M \coth(\sqrt M s) (g_M - ds^2).$$

If we throw away the $-ds^2$ we get the estimate $$|\nabla^2 s_M| \le \sqrt M \coth(\sqrt M s)|g_M|.$$

Since $|g_M| = \sqrt{g^{ij}g_{ij}} = \sqrt n$ depends only on the dimension $n$, the theorem (along with an upper bound for $\coth$ you can try proving) gives us the estimate $$|\nabla^2 s| \le |\nabla^2 s_M| \le \sqrt {nM} \coth \sqrt M s \le \sqrt n \left(\sqrt M + \frac1s\right).$$

It *looks* like the authors have a slightly better estimate here with $\sqrt M$ instead of $\sqrt {nM}$ - I'm not sure whether the mistake is mine or theirs. (Taking the $-ds^2$ in to account only improves the $\sqrt n$ to $\sqrt{n-1}$.) It doesn't matter anyway, since we can still choose a constant $C_3$ dependent only on dimension that makes it work.

Comment: Really thanks , if you don't tell me ,I think I still can't understand it after long time.

Comment: In $g_M = ds^2 + \frac1M \sinh^2(\sqrt M s) d\Omega^2$, the $s$ of $\sqrt M s$  is $s(x)$ ? How does it ? They are on different manifold .

Comment: @lanse2pty: the $s$ is just the radial coordinate on each manifold, I gave them the same name to make the comparison simpler.

Comment: If so , in the last inequality , $|\nabla^2 s| \le \sqrt n \left(\sqrt M + \frac1s\right).$ the first $s$ is not the second $s $,

Comment: @lanse2pty: the comparison theorem could be more precisely stated as $|\nabla^2 s(x)| \le |\nabla^2 s_M(p)|$ where $p$ is a point in the hyperbolic space such that $s_M(p) = s(x)$. You could also think of my equation for $g_M$ as defining a hyperbolic metric *on the original manifold* in geodesic polar coordinates, in which case they really are the same $s$.

Comment: Let me think...

Comment: I understand it by this way : $(M,g)$ is the original manifold ,and $s(x)=d_g(x,s(0))$ is the geodesic distance function, so ,we can choice $s$ as  coordinate.Then on the new coordinate (still on $M$, just change the coordinate and metric), we define the metric by $g_M = ds^2 + \frac1M \sinh^2(\sqrt M s) d\Omega^2$, and let $s_M(x)=d_{g_M}(x,s(0))$, then compare $\nabla^2s$ and $\nabla^2 s_M$

Comment: I think it use the below Hessian Compare

Comment: @lanse2pty: this is essentially the same but with a slightly weaker curvature assumption (though I think they forgot to stipulate $|X_1| = |X_2|$).

Comment: Thanks very much ,although I still have a little fuzzy with it ,but I think I just need time to think it again.

Comment: How to compute the curvature of $(M,g_M)$?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518259/curvature-of-given-metric-space

Answer (score 0):

I just using this Hessian comparison,which I am familiar with.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Excuse me, what book is this? Thanks