# Compute of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

In the answer of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499968/how-to-show-the-inequation-by-using-hessian-comparison),for the given metric 
$$g_M = ds^2 + \frac1M \sinh^2(\sqrt M s) d\Omega^2,$$ 
how to compute the curvature? Whether the hyperbolic space means $M=\{x\in R^n:x_n>0\}$?

Besides, I also don't know how to compute $\nabla^2s_M $.

I think my foundation of Riemannian geometry is very weak, hope for detail answer, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the hyperbolic manifold is the manifold $(\mathbb R^n , g)$ given by one chart $\mathbb R^n$, where in spherical coordinates $(\theta^0= s, \theta^1, \cdots, \theta^{n-1})$, the metric is given by 
$$\tag{1} g = ds^2 + \frac1M \sinh^2(\sqrt M s) d\Omega^2.$$
Note that this is fairly explicit. The manifold you have in mind
$$\{ x\in \mathbb R^n : x_n >0\}$$
is just another realization of the hyperbolic manifold. However in that coordinates $(x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}, x_n)$, the metric is of different form: It's

$$g = \frac{1}{x_n^2} \left( dx_1^2 + \cdots dx_n^2\right).$$

But in our situation $(1)$ is more suitable as the Hessian $\nabla^2 s$ you want to calculate are already given by the spherical coordinates $s = \theta^0$.

By definition, $\nabla^2 s$ is a $(0,2)$-tensor given by

$$\nabla^2_{ij} s = \frac{ \partial^2 s}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} -\Gamma_{ij}^k \frac{\partial s}{\partial x^k}.$$

If we use the polar coordinates $(\theta^0= s, \theta^1, \cdots, \theta^{n-1})$, then as $\frac{\partial \theta^0}{\partial \theta^i} = \delta_{0i}$,

$$\nabla^2 _{ij} s = - \Gamma_{ij}^0 .$$

The Christoffel symbols is given by 
$$\begin{split} \Gamma_{ij}^0 &= \frac{1}{2} g^{k0} \left(\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial \theta^i} + \frac{\partial g_{ki}}{\partial \theta^j}- \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial \theta^k}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial g_{j0}}{\partial \theta^i} + \frac{\partial g_{0i}}{\partial \theta^j}- \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial \theta^0}\right)\\
&= -\frac 12 \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial \theta^0}
\end{split}$$
as $g_{i0}$ is always constant (either $1$ or $0$). So 
$$\nabla^2_{ij}s = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if either }i= 0 \text{ or }j= 0 \\\frac{1}{\sqrt M} \sinh(\sqrt M s)\cosh(\sqrt M s) \left\langle \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta^i},  \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta^i} \right\rangle & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

(Note here $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle $ is the standard metric on the unit sphere). Thus

$$\nabla^2 s = \frac{1}{\sqrt M}\sinh(\sqrt M s)\cosh(\sqrt M s) d\Omega ^2,$$

as claimed in Anthony's answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31222/discussion-on-answer-by-john-ma-compute-of-curvature).

Comment: @DanielFischer  I think you should not move the comments to chat.Because if a newcomer  don't understand my prime question ,maybe ,he also has the same question in comment.If move it to chat, for these newcomer ,he must ask again.Besides, the chat is not compatible with Latex .Thanks.