# Curvature of given metric space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

As my question [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499968/how-to-show-the-inequation-by-using-hessian-comparison) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517242/compute-of-curvature/1517272#1517272), I still have many problems.

First, the hyperbolic manifold is the manifold $(\mathbb R^n , g)$ given by one chart $\mathbb R^n$, where in spherical coordinates $(\theta^0= s, \theta^1, \cdots, \theta^{n-1})$, the metric is given by 
$$\tag{1} g = ds^2 + \frac1M \sinh^2(\sqrt M s) d\Omega^2.$$
I want to compute the curvature of $(\mathbb R^n,g)$.I try to compute $\Gamma_{ij}^k$, but in different dimension,$d\Omega^2$ has different form , I can't get $g_{ij} $ for $i,j\ne0$.Then ,I don't know how to do it .

Comment: @John Ma  Could you  teach me compute the curvature ?Or give some hint about deal $d\Omega^2$ ?

Comment: See e.g. Petersen chapters 2 and 3, particularly the rotationally symmetric warped product example. Once you've established his "fundamental equations" this is quite simple. The core of the idea is to apply the Gauss-Codazzi relations to the hyperspheres of constant $s$, which have known curvature.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  I try it in the below . But it is too complex when I compute the $\Gamma_{ij}^k$.And it's far from the curvature. If according my way, I need to compute the $R^k_{ijl}=\frac {\partial\Gamma_{jl}^k}{\partial x^i} ...$. It's so much compute and complex. Whether there are any easy way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) If $M>0$, define $$ \phi(s):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}} \sinh\
\sqrt{M}s,\ g_N:=dr^2 +\phi(r)^2 g_{S^{n-1}}$$

In this case we have a formula $$ K_{rad} = - \frac{\phi''}{\phi} $$

$$ K_{sph} = \frac{1-(\phi')^2}{\phi } $$

So in this case we have $$ K_{rad}=K_{sph}=-M $$

(2) Now we will prove that these formula : For $p=(r,\theta)\in
N={\bf R}^n$, consider $$ \exp_\theta : T_\theta S^{n-1}\rightarrow
S^{n-1} $$ Here $S^{n-1}$ has normal coordinate\

$$ F: {\bf R}^n={\bf R}\times T_\theta S^{n-1} \rightarrow N ,\ F(r, v) =
(r,\exp_\theta v ) $$

That is $$ (g_N)_{ij}=g_N(dF e_i, dF e_j) =\phi(r)^2 \delta_{ij} $$

(2.1) Here sectional curvature for radial direction is given by
$$K_{rad} =( D_{\partial_r}D_{\partial_{\theta }}
\partial_{\theta } - D_{\partial_{\theta} } D_{\partial_r}
\partial_{\theta } ,
\partial_r  )\frac{1}{|\partial_\theta |^2}$$ since $\partial_r\perp
\partial_{\theta} $ where $\partial_\theta = \partial_{\theta_i} =dF\ e_i $ for some $i$

Here
$$D_{\partial_r}\partial_r=0,\ \Gamma_{r\theta_j}^r=0
$$

If $(D_{\partial_\theta }\partial_r,\partial_{\theta_k})=0\ \ast$
for $i\neq k$ (cf. $(\nabla_{\ } \partial_r,\ )$ is **symmetric** so
that it can be diagonalized), then
$$\Gamma_{\theta\theta}^r=-\phi\phi',\ \Gamma_{\theta_jr}^{\theta_j}=\phi'/\phi $$

$$
K_{rad} =\frac{1}{|\partial_\theta |^2} \{ -\frac{1}{2}\partial_r^2
(
\partial_\theta,
\partial_{\theta } ) + |D_{
\partial_{\theta } } \partial_r |^2  \} = -\frac{\phi''}{\phi }$$

(2.2) $$K_{sph} =( D_{\partial_{\theta_j} }D_{\partial_{\theta }}
\partial_{\theta } - D_{\partial_{\theta} } D_{\partial_{\theta_j} }
\partial_{\theta } ,
\partial_{\theta_j}  )\frac{1}{\phi^4}$$ $$ = \frac{1}{\phi^2} \{ \underbrace{\partial_{\theta_j}
\Gamma_{\theta\theta}^{\theta_j} -\partial_\theta\Gamma_{\theta_j
\theta}^{\theta_j} +
\Gamma_{\theta\theta}^{\theta_k}\Gamma_{\theta_j\theta_k}^{\theta_j}
-
\Gamma_{\theta_j\theta}^{\theta_k}\Gamma_{\theta\theta_k}^{\theta_j}}_{=1}
\} + \frac{1}{\phi^2} \{
\Gamma_{\theta\theta}^r\Gamma_{\theta_jr}^{\theta_j} -
\underbrace{\Gamma_{\theta_j\theta}^r\Gamma_{\theta
r}^{\theta_j}}_{=0\ by\ \ast} \}
$$

( Here $\Gamma_{\theta\theta_k}^{\theta_j}$ is clearly $
\Gamma_{\theta\theta_k}^{\theta_j} (g_N)$ Since $\phi$ is a function
independent of $\theta_i$, then we have $
\Gamma_{\theta\theta_k}^{\theta_j}=\Gamma_{\theta\theta_k}^{\theta_j}
(g_{S^{n-1} })$ )

Comment: Really thank you very much.

Comment: In the last equation ,how to show $\Gamma_{\theta_j\theta}^r\Gamma_{\theta r}^{\theta_j}=-1$?

Comment: I don't know where   the 1 of $\frac{1-(\phi')^2}{\phi^2}$  is from.

Comment: I added more explanation

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know why $\partial_{\theta_j}
\Gamma_{\theta\theta}^{\theta_j} -\partial_\theta\Gamma_{\theta_j
\theta}^{\theta_j} +
\Gamma_{\theta\theta}^{\theta_k}\Gamma_{\theta_j\theta_k}^{\theta_j}
-
\Gamma_{\theta_j\theta}^{\theta_k}\Gamma_{\theta\theta_k}^{\theta_j}=1$

Comment: If $\theta_i\rightarrow i$, then $\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac{1}{2}(g_N)^{ks} ((g_N)_{si,j} + (g_N)_{sj,i} - (g_N)_{ij,s} ) $ where $s=i$ or $\partial_r$ But by $g_N$, we don't need to consider the case $s=\partial_r$ So $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ is in fact that of $S^{n-1}$ That is term you indicated is curvature of $S^{n-1}$

Comment: @HKLee   I compute out the $\partial_{\theta_j} \Gamma_{\theta\theta}^{\theta_j} -\partial_\theta\Gamma_{\theta_j \theta}^{\theta_j} + \Gamma_{\theta\theta}^{\theta_k}\Gamma_{\theta_j\theta_k}^{\theta_j} - \Gamma_{\theta_j\theta}^{\theta_k}\Gamma_{\theta\theta_k}^{\theta_j}$ is  the scalar curvature of $S^{n-1}$ , right ?