# Hessian comparison

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

I get stuck in the red line in picture below.

I want to comparison it with the manifold which curvature is $M>|R|$,because the curvature is uniformly bounded  for $t\in[0,T]$.But I am really unfamiliar with using comparison theorem.May I have some hint or answer?

The picture below is from the 210 page of this [paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Hu6.png).

> [image]

Comment: Upvote because I hate it when sloppy referees let the phrase 'well known' (without citation) pass.

Comment: The function f is defined in a way that its first and second covariant derivative depend on the derivatives of the distance function. The gradient of the distance function is 1 almost everywhere and the hessian of the distance function can be estimated using the Hessian comparison theorem. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499968/how-to-show-the-inequation-by-using-hessian-comparison).